# AWS: Network ACL configured to accept traffic only from another Network ACL

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am pretty new to CloudFormation. I am creating a VPC, Subnets and security groups. I would also want to create an ACL for each subnet in my VPC.

From what I understand, ACL is a way to assign a firewall rule to all the resources that are held by a given subnet. Please, correct me if i am wrong.

The problem is that i would like to configure an ACL so that all the resources within it can only accept traffic from resources within another ACL.

I know it is possible to create a security groups that only accepts traffic from another security group.

My CloudFormation template would be:

```
webSubnetACL:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::NetworkAcl'
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref managementVpc

  webSubnetAssociation:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::SubnetNetworkAclAssociation'
    Properties:
      NetworkAclId: !Ref webSubnetACL
      SubnetId: !Ref webSubnet

  fromWorldHTTP:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::NetworkAclEntry'
    Properties:
      NetworkAclId: !Ref webSubnetACL
      RuleNumber: '300'
      Protocol: '6'
      PortRange:
        From: 80
        To: 80
      RuleAction: allow
      CidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
fromWeb:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::NetworkAclEntry'
    Properties:
      NetworkAclId: !Ref dbSubnetACL
      RuleNumber: '102'
      Protocol: '6'
      PortRange:
        From: 3600
        To: 3600
      RuleAction: allow
      CidrBlock: 10.0.0.0/25
```

So in this case there would be 2 subnets : webSubnet, that will hold web servers, and dbSubnet that will hold databases THAT MUST GRANT CONNECTION ONLY TO resources in webSubnet.
In fromWeb resource i am not able to reference the fromWorldHTTP resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot reference any AWS logical resources in your NACL rules (such as a NACL, ENI or Security Group).

If you want to whitelist you must add an explicit CIDR range of the subnets that you want to allow ingress/egress connections for.

If any of the subnet ranges are together you may be able to supernet the ranges together to reduce the number of rules.

Answer (score 1):

> i am not able to reference the fromWorldHTTP resource.

You can't do this, because its not possible. **NACLs can't reference other NACLs**. In contrast SGs can reference other SGs, as you pointed out.

NACL rules are **soley based on IP addresses and IP ranges**. Thus, you have to reference IP ranges only in your NACLs.